# It is possible to Restore context menu

Tags: javascript

I'm blocking context menu, then I want to restore it to previous state.

```
myElement = document.querySelector('*');
myElement.addEventListener('contextmenu', MyContextMenu);
```

it is possible to restore default context menu after the above code have been executed ?
if the answer is yes then how or how to make it correctly?

what i want is to block context menu and then restore it after a while.

Comment: Not sure if i understand your question correctly, but you could call `myElement.removeEventListener('contextmenu', MyContextMenu);` at the time where you don't want to have `MyContextMenu` to be called anymore for the next invocations of the contextmenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var oldHandlerToKeep = element.oncontextmenu
```

Comment: it is possible to pass it as parameter as: `myElement.addEventListener('contextmenu', MyContextMenu(myElement.oncontextmenu));`

Comment: if I can pass old handler to new handler then this answer is pretty enough for me

Comment: This would only work if the other handler was set with `element.oncontextmenu = AnotherHandler;`, but not if it was registered with `element.addEventListener('contextmenu', AnotherHandler);`. Anyway as long as `MyContextMenu` does not return `false`, stops propagation or prevents the default behavior, the other handlers (including the default on) should also be called, because `addEventListener` does not overwrite the existing handlers, but just adds an additional one.

Comment: well then I ***guess*** setting is to NULL would mean getting back to the standard one

Comment: doing `element.oncontextmenu = null;` would not remove a listener added with `element.addEventListener('contextmenu', ... )`.

Comment: well, then it means that the default handler is not exposed at all, it should work then by just calling removeEventListener passing whatever handler was assigned via addEventHandler

Answer (score 5):

Reassign all context menus to default:

```js
document.querySelector('div').oncontextmenu = _=>false;

var d = document.createElement('div').oncontextmenu;
[...document.querySelectorAll("*")].forEach(e => e.oncontextmenu = d);
```

```html
<div>sample</div>
```

---

### Update

Here is a modern version with the "prevent" concept:

```js
document.querySelector('div').oncontextmenu = e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  return false
}

const fn = document.createElement('div').oncontextmenu
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(el => el.oncontextmenu = fn)
```

```html
<div>sample</div>
```

**Note:** This ***will not work*** if the event is assigned as an event listener:

```js
document.querySelector('div')
  .addEventListener('contextmenu', e => {
    e.preventDefault() // <-- problem
    return false
  })

const fn = document.createElement('div').oncontextmenu
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(el => el.oncontextmenu = fn)
```

```html
<div>sample</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate solution (based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335136/how-to-re-enable-right-click-so-that-i-can-inspect-html-elements-in-chrome/57065599#57065599) by [Chema](https://stackoverflow.com/users/564148/chema)):

```
    document.body.oncontextmenu = null;
    document.addEventListener("contextmenu",
        function (event) {
            event.returnValue = true;
            if (typeof(event.stopPropagation) === 'function')
            {
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
            if (typeof(event.cancelBubble) === 'function')
            {
                event.cancelBubble();
            }
        }, true);
```

This helps to restore the context menu if `preventDefault()` was previously called. Hopefully it might help some passersby.