# How to re-enable right click so that I can inspect HTML elements in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am looking at a web page which has overwritten the right-click button so to display its own popup HTML element.

This prevents me from using Chrome Developer Tools to inspect elements.

Does anybody know a JavaScript snippet I could inject from the Chrome Console
to re-enable the right-click?

I am okay to break the existing 'right-click' functionality, so to be able to inspect the HTML elements easily.

Comment: if you use firebug for firefox you can still highlight elements with the mouse... I know it means using Firefox but it might be helpful.

Comment: @Teemu Firebug Lite is available on Chrome. Not sure why you'd need to use it over the default tools though.

Comment: @JoshSmickus The question is tagged with [google-chrome], also OP asks how to use _Chrome developer tools_ to inspect elements.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

If they have just changed the `oncontextmenu` handler (which is the most straightforward way to do it), then you can remove their override thus:

```
window.oncontextmenu = null;
```

Otherwise, if it is attached to individual elements, you can get all the page's elements, and then remove the handler on each one:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for(var id = 0; id < elements.length; ++id) { elements[id].oncontextmenu = null; }
```

Or, it seems you can turn off such scripts; [via an extension in Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-right-click/hompjdfbfmmmgflfjdlnkohcplmboaeo?hl=en) or an [option in Firefox](http://www.wikihow.com/Disable-%22No-Right-Click%22-Scripts-in-Firefox) - in the advanced box for javascript options, switch off 'Disable or replace context menus'.

Answer (score 71):

Tested in Chrome 60.0.3112.78.

Some of the above methods work, but the easiest in my opinion is:

1. Open dev tools (Shift+Control+i).
2. Select the "Elements" tab, and then the "Event Listeners" tab.
3. Hover over the elements/listener. A "Remove" button will show up.
4. Click "Remove".

E.g. see photo.

[image: Remove event listener]

Comment: This actually works great, but I'd add a step between 1 and 2, to use the selector tool (arrow) top left corner, to select the element from the web page first.  
Then pop over to Elements  Event Listeners and remove the click or in my case, the contextmenu events.   Then can right click and do whatever you want.

Answer (score 48):

This bookmarlet works in Google sites/Youtube as of Aug 2019 (tested in Chrome and Firefox):

```
function enableContextMenu(aggressive = false) { 
void(document.ondragstart=null); 
void(document.onselectstart=null); 
void(document.onclick=null); 
void(document.onmousedown=null); 
void(document.onmouseup=null); 
void(document.body.oncontextmenu=null); 
enableRightClickLight(document); 
if (aggressive) { 
  enableRightClick(document); 
  removeContextMenuOnAll("body"); 
  removeContextMenuOnAll("img"); 
  removeContextMenuOnAll("td"); 
  } } 

function removeContextMenuOnAll(tagName) { 
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName); 
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { 
    enableRightClick(elements[i]); 
  } 
} 

function enableRightClickLight(el) { 
  el || (el = document); 
  el.addEventListener("contextmenu", bringBackDefault, true); 
} 

function enableRightClick(el) { 
  el || (el = document); 
  el.addEventListener("contextmenu", bringBackDefault, true); 
  el.addEventListener("dragstart", bringBackDefault, true); 
  el.addEventListener("selectstart", bringBackDefault, true); 
  el.addEventListener("click", bringBackDefault, true); 
  el.addEventListener("mousedown", bringBackDefault, true); 
  el.addEventListener("mouseup", bringBackDefault, true); 
} 

function restoreRightClick(el) { 
  el || (el = document); 
  el.removeEventListener("contextmenu", bringBackDefault, true); 
  el.removeEventListener("dragstart", bringBackDefault, true); 
  el.removeEventListener("selectstart", bringBackDefault, true); 
  el.removeEventListener("click", bringBackDefault, true); 
  el.removeEventListener("mousedown", bringBackDefault, true); 
  el.removeEventListener("mouseup", bringBackDefault, true); 
} 
function bringBackDefault(event) {
  event.returnValue = true; 
  (typeof event.stopPropagation === 'function') && 
  event.stopPropagation(); 
  (typeof event.cancelBubble === 'function') && 
  event.cancelBubble(); 
} 

enableContextMenu();
```

For peskier sites, set/pass aggressive to true (this will disable most event handlers and hence disable interaction with the page):

```
function enableContextMenu(aggressive = true) { 
  void(document.ondragstart=null);
  void(document.onselectstart=null);
  void(document.onclick=null);
  void(document.onmousedown=null);
  void(document.onmouseup=null); 
  void(document.body.oncontextmenu=null); 
  enableRightClickLight(document); 
  if (aggressive) {
    enableRightClick(document);
    removeContextMenuOnAll("body");
    removeContextMenuOnAll("img");
    removeContextMenuOnAll("td");
  }
} 

function removeContextMenuOnAll(tagName) {
 var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { enableRightClick(elements[i]);
  }
} 

function enableRightClickLight(el) { 
  el || (el = document); 
  el.addEventListener("contextmenu", bringBackDefault, true); 
}

function enableRightClick(el) {
  el || (el = document);
  el.addEventListener("contextmenu", bringBackDefault, true); 
  el.addEventListener("dragstart", bringBackDefault, true); 
  el.addEventListener("selectstart", bringBackDefault, true); 
  el.addEventListener("click", bringBackDefault, true); 
  el.addEventListener("mousedown", bringBackDefault, true); 
  el.addEventListener("mouseup", bringBackDefault, true); 
} 

function restoreRightClick(el) {
  el || (el = document);
  el.removeEventListener("contextmenu", bringBackDefault, true); 
  el.removeEventListener("dragstart", bringBackDefault, true); 
  el.removeEventListener("selectstart", bringBackDefault, true); 
  el.removeEventListener("click", bringBackDefault, true); 
  el.removeEventListener("mousedown", bringBackDefault, true); 
  el.removeEventListener("mouseup", bringBackDefault, true);
} 

function bringBackDefault(event) {
  event.returnValue = true;
  (typeof event.stopPropagation === 'function') && 
  event.stopPropagation();
  (typeof event.cancelBubble === 'function') &&
  event.cancelBubble(); 
} 

enableContextMenu();
```

Answer (score 36):

I built upon @Chema solution and added resetting `pointer-events` and `user-select`. If they are set to `none` for an image, right-clicking it does not invoke the context menu for the image with options to view or save it.

```
javascript:function enableContextMenu(aggressive = true) { void(document.ondragstart=null); void(document.onselectstart=null); void(document.onclick=null); void(document.onmousedown=null); void(document.onmouseup=null); void(document.body.oncontextmenu=null); enableRightClickLight(document); if (aggressive) { enableRightClick(document); removeContextMenuOnAll('body'); removeContextMenuOnAll('img'); removeContextMenuOnAll('td'); } } function removeContextMenuOnAll(tagName) { var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName); for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { enableRightClick(elements[i]); enablePointerEvents(elements[i]); } } function enableRightClickLight(el) { el || (el = document); el.addEventListener('contextmenu', bringBackDefault, true); } function enableRightClick(el) { el || (el = document); el.addEventListener('contextmenu', bringBackDefault, true); el.addEventListener('dragstart', bringBackDefault, true); el.addEventListener('selectstart', bringBackDefault, true); el.addEventListener('click', bringBackDefault, true); el.addEventListener('mousedown', bringBackDefault, true); el.addEventListener('mouseup', bringBackDefault, true); } function restoreRightClick(el) { el || (el = document); el.removeEventListener('contextmenu', bringBackDefault, true); el.removeEventListener('dragstart', bringBackDefault, true); el.removeEventListener('selectstart', bringBackDefault, true); el.removeEventListener('click', bringBackDefault, true); el.removeEventListener('mousedown', bringBackDefault, true); el.removeEventListener('mouseup', bringBackDefault, true); } function bringBackDefault(event) { event.returnValue = true; (typeof event.stopPropagation === 'function') && event.stopPropagation(); (typeof event.cancelBubble === 'function') && event.cancelBubble(); } function enablePointerEvents(el) {  if (!el) return; el.style.pointerEvents='auto'; el.style.webkitTouchCallout='default'; el.style.webkitUserSelect='auto'; el.style.MozUserSelect='auto'; el.style.msUserSelect='auto'; el.style.userSelect='auto'; enablePointerEvents(el.parentElement); } enableContextMenu();
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. This is really more aggressive than the solution in [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21335527/14928633).

Answer (score 23):

Easiest thing to do is open the dev tools by pressing Cmd + Opt + I (Mac) or F12 (PC). You can then use the search (magnifying glass, top left on the dev tools toolbar) to select the element.

Comment: or can do Ctrl (Cmd) + Shift + C to open directly  the 'element selection' functionality

Answer (score 18):

you can use following code for re-enable mouse right click.

```
document.oncontextmenu = function(){}
```

and you can use shortcut key (Ctrl+Shift+i) to open inspect elements in chrome in windows OS.

Comment: This works like a charm! If you have to do this often like me, you can add it as a bookmarklet: Create a new bookmark, and put as URL:
javascript:(document.oncontextmenu = function(){})()
Now, each time you have a page that bugs you, just click the bookmarklet and done.

Answer (score 7):

Another possible way, when the blocking function is made with jquery, use:

```
$(document).unbind();
```

It will clear all the onmousedown and contextmenu events attributed dynamically, that can't be erased with document.contextmenu=null; etc.

Comment: same for me, some code did a re-bind: `$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){if(!$('#easyy').length)e.preventDefault();});`

Answer (score 7):

You could use `javascript:void(document.oncontextmenu=null);`
open Browser console and run the code above. It will turn off blockin' of mouse right button

Answer (score 3):

On the very left of the Chrome Developer Tools toolbar there is a button that lets you select an item to inspect regardless of context menu handlers. It looks like a [square with arrow pointing to the center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPmWb.png).

Answer (score 2):

To re-enable the right-click functionality on a webpage where it has been disabled, you can use the following JavaScript snippet in your browser's console:

```js
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.stopPropagation(), true);
```

This code works by adding an event listener for the `contextmenu` event (which is typically triggered by a right-click). The listener uses `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent any further propagation of the event in the capturing and bubbling phases. The `true` argument at the end ensures that this event listener is executed in the capturing phase, which often occurs before the event listeners that disable the right-click functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have a shorter version. this does same as a best answer.
(it works on chrome 74.03)

```
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(e => e.oncontextmenu = null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Open inspect mode before navigating to the page.
It worked.hehe

Answer (score 1):

Not quite answering the question, but you can use ctrl/cmd + shift + c to start an "inspect on hover" mode in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

As of October 3rd, 2023.

To open chrome dev tools, you have to press `CMD + ALT + I` on mac.

This solution involves resetting the `pointer-events` and `user-select` CSS properties for the element, setting them both to "none." Consequently, users won't be presented with the usual context menu options to view or save the image when right-clicking on it.

```js
javascript:function enableContextMenu(aggressive = true) { void(document.ondragstart=null); void(document.onselectstart=null); void(document.onclick=null); void(document.onmousedown=null); void(document.onmouseup=null); void(document.body.oncontextmenu=null); enableRightClickLight(document); if (aggressive) { enableRightClick(document); removeContextMenuOnAll('body'); removeContextMenuOnAll('img'); removeContextMenuOnAll('td'); } } function removeContextMenuOnAll(tagName) { var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName); for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { enableRightClick(elements[i]); enablePointerEvents(elements[i]); } } function enableRightClickLight(el) { el || (el = document); el.addEventListener('contextmenu', bringBackDefault, true); } function enableRightClick(el) { el || (el = document); el.addEventListener('contextmenu', bringBackDefault, true); el.addEventListener('dragstart', bringBackDefault, true); el.addEventListener('selectstart', bringBackDefault, true); el.addEventListener('click', bringBackDefault, true); el.addEventListener('mousedown', bringBackDefault, true); el.addEventListener('mouseup', bringBackDefault, true); } function restoreRightClick(el) { el || (el = document); el.removeEventListener('contextmenu', bringBackDefault, true); el.removeEventListener('dragstart', bringBackDefault, true); el.removeEventListener('selectstart', bringBackDefault, true); el.removeEventListener('click', bringBackDefault, true); el.removeEventListener('mousedown', bringBackDefault, true); el.removeEventListener('mouseup', bringBackDefault, true); } function bringBackDefault(event) { event.returnValue = true; (typeof event.stopPropagation === 'function') && event.stopPropagation(); (typeof event.cancelBubble === 'function') && event.cancelBubble(); } function enablePointerEvents(el) {  if (!el) return; el.style.pointerEvents='auto'; el.style.webkitTouchCallout='default'; el.style.webkitUserSelect='auto'; el.style.MozUserSelect='auto'; el.style.msUserSelect='auto'; el.style.userSelect='auto'; enablePointerEvents(el.parentElement); } enableContextMenu();
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the "SETTINGS > PRIVACY > don´t allow JavaScript" in Chrome will enable the right click function and allow the Firebug Console to work; but will also disable all the other JavaScript codes.

The right way to do this is to disable only the specific JavaScript; looking for any of the following lines of code:

- Function disableclick
- Function click … return false;
- body oncontextmenu="return false;"

Answer (score 0):

I just visited [this](http://hackingzz.blogspot.co.il/2011/03/analyzing-side-channel-attacks-on.html) site and it really bugged me,

apparently there are a couple ways to disable the mouse click:

1)

```
<script language="javascript">
document.onmousedown=disableclick;
status="Right Click Disabled";
function disableclick(event)
{
  if(event.button==2)
   {
     alert(status);
     return false;    
   }
}
</script>
```

and

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
```

...

in this case what you will have to do in the dev tools is :

```
document.removeEventListener("onmousedown",disableclick);
document.oncontextmenu = function(){}
```

2)

using flash as a content wrapper - no solution here except taking a screenshot

3)

some sites want to prevent downloading images via right click -> save image as

so what they do is put this:

```
<div style="background-image: url(YourImage.jpg);">
   <img src="transparent.gif"/>
</div>
```

which is a transparent image spreding on the full width and height of the screen all you need to do is go to the elements inspector and find the div and delete it.

In my case #1 did the trick

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was delete the event listeners on the page. After I did that, I was able to copy the text and paste it in to my processor of choice.

Answer (score 0):

If the page you are on has a **text** or **textarea** input, click into this input (as if you want to enter text) then **right-click** and select '**Inspect element**'.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the other comments works, just do, open console line command and type:

```
document.oncontextmenu = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Press `Ctrl+Control+F12`
Then select `Elements` > `Event Listeners` > `Remove contextmenu events`

Answer (score 0):

I tried many of the solutions above, but the following worked fine for me:

```
$(document).unbind();
```

This code will unbind all event handlers that were attached to the document using the `on()` method. This can be useful if you need to remove a specific event handler or if you want to start fresh with a new set of event handlers.

To run this code, you will need to open the developer tools in your browser. In Chrome, you can do this by pressing Ctrl+Shift+I. Once the developer tools are open, switch to the console tab. Then, paste the code above into the console and press enter.

The code should execute without any errors. If it does, you should see a message in the console that says All event handlers unbound. This means that the code has successfully removed all event handlers from the document.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is most likely partly or entirely written by an AI. Please read Stack Overflow's guidelines on AI content: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way I found is to open the webpage in Read mode (browser that supports read mode like Safari, Firefox etc) and then copy as usual

Answer (score -4):

Just **Press F12**

Go to **Sources**

There you will find **Enable right click**. Click on it.

Under this you will find **web_accessible_resource**.

Open it in this you will find **index.js**.

Press **Ctrl + F** and search for **disabelRightClick**. There you will find

```
        var disableRightClick = false;
```

this line. Replace this line with

```
        var disableRightClick = true;
```

Just press   **Ctrl + s**

!! Done. Now your right click is enabled !!