# enabling right click: <body oncontextmenu="return false">

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've a web page(which I don't control) with:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
```

I want to enable right click but there's no way I'm able to do it. In the saved html when I removed this `oncontextmenu` then it started working.

I've tried all mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335136/how-to-re-enable-right-click-so-that-i-can-inspect-html-elements-in-chrome/21335218), but it's not working for me.

[Here is](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7aEugGV1GwTd29PdmRfYmZjR00/view?usp=sharing) the saved copy of web page.

Comment: Remove the `oncontextmenu="return false"` attribute...?

Comment: I don't control the webpage

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687790/how-to-remove-onclick-with-jquery

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've tried `$("body").prop('onclick', null).off('click');` but does not work

Comment: @user5858 If you don't control the web page then how you can enable the right click? This line `oncontextmenu="return false"` is clearly saying that you have intentionally disabled the right click. In order to enable the right click, you need to remove this attribute.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to execute the bellow code in webdev console :

```js
window.addEventListener("contextmenu", 
  function(e){
     e.stopPropagation()
}, true);
```

```css
body,html {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
 text
</body>
```

Comment: I'm Glad .Great =) . !

Answer (score 1):

In 2022 and for Firefox you must place the oncontextmenu attribut to the html tag not to the body tag

```
<html oncontextmenu="return false">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {e.stopPropagation();e.preventDefault();}, true);
```

**in body & html**

```
<html oncontextmenu="return false">
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
```

I hope it helps navigators.